# restlet odata pojo generator errors

Tags: java, xml, maven, odata, restlet

Using .net tooling, I have been able create an ODATA service endpoint that exposes a legacy MSSQL database.  It was my intent to then use odata4j to communicate to it.  However, lacking pojos, I turned to restlet.  I made all entities visible in the service, but when I run the restlet generator it fails to generate pojos saying:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.restlet.ext.xml.SaxRepresentation.parse(SaxRepresentation.java:230)
at org.restlet.ext.odata.internal.edm.Metadata.<init>(Metadata.java:79)
at org.restlet.ext.odata.Service.getMetadata(Service.java:488)
at org.restlet.ext.odata.Generator.main(Generator.java:137)
...
Can't get the metadata for `http://localhost:53088/ODataService.svc/`
...
java.io.IOException: Couldn't parse the source representation: java.io.IOException: The thread blocked at the cyclic barrier has timed out.
at org.restlet.ext.xml.SaxRepresentation.parse(SaxRepresentation.java:238)
at org.restlet.ext.odata.internal.edm.Metadata.<init>(Metadata.java:79)
at org.restlet.ext.odata.Service.getMetadata(Service.java:488)
at org.restlet.ext.odata.Generator.main(Generator.java:137)
at xxx.model.generator.ModelGenerator.main(ModelGenerator.java:12)
```

I decided to trim down the ODATA service to a single simple entity and try the code generation and it worked!  But as I enabled more entities, I received an XML parsing error:

```
Can't get the metadata for `http://localhost:53088/ODataService.svc/`
java.io.IOException: Couldn't parse the source representation:\
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: XML document structures must start and end within \
the same entity.
    at org.restlet.ext.xml.SaxRepresentation.parse(SaxRepresentation.java:238)
    at org.restlet.ext.odata.internal.edm.Metadata.<init>(Metadata.java:79)
    at org.restlet.ext.odata.Service.getMetadata(Service.java:488)
    at org.restlet.ext.odata.Generator.main(Generator.java:137)
    at xxx.model.generator.ModelGenerator.main(ModelGenerator.java:12)
An error occurred: 
Cannot retrieve the metadata.
```

Anyways, it seems to dislike the xml after some number of entities, rather than disliking a specific entity. Also the XML from `http://localhost:53088/ODataService.svc/$metadata` is valid with no errors.

Here is the Generator code:

```
import org.restlet.ext.odata.Generator;

public class ModelGenerator
{
    public static final String [] URL_WORKSPACE = { "http://localhost:53088/ODataService.svc/", "src/main/java/"};

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Generator.main(URL_WORKSPACE);
    }
}
```

Here are my maven POM details:

```
    <properties>
        <org.odata4j.version>0.7.0</org.odata4j.version>
        <org.restlet.version>2.1.4</org.restlet.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.odata4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>odata4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
            <version>${org.restlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.odata</artifactId>
            <version>${org.restlet.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: The code appears to be falling over because the XML parsed is not well formed.  Does the URL ('http://localhost:53088/ODataService.svc/') produce XML that validates correctly?  if yes is it all being retrieved in one go or is it being chunked?

Comment: I am not sure.  Do you know how I can check this?

Comment: And yes, it does generate valid XML.

Comment: Check the HTTP headers for encodings.